# Error code 127 attaching Docker Devcontainer with Devcontainers extension in VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm new to the Docker and Containers world and I was trying to attach a container to the VS Code using the Devcontainers extension on VS Code.

Unfortunately an error 127 appears and I don't manage to sort it out.

Here's the error code:

```
[2433 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-53e9f905-3100-4ebf-ad4b-88c2eb77280c.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-server-53e9f905-3100-4ebf-ad4b-88c2eb77280c.js_1688027205219
[2436 ms] 
[2436 ms] 
[2439 ms] Container server: Error relocating /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/node: _ZNSt19_Sp_make_shared_tag5_S_eqERKSt9type_info: symbol not found
[2439 ms] Container server: Error relocating /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
[2474 ms] Error: stream ended with:0 but wanted:9
        at c (c:\Users\tuddan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.295.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:101670)
        at c:\Users\tuddan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.295.0\dist\extension\extension.js:24:101851
        at s (c:\Users\tuddan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.295.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:5371)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (c:\Users\tuddan\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.295.0\dist\extension\extension.js:27:5541)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
        at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
[2474 ms] Start: Run in container: mkdir -p '/tmp/devcontainers-16d69df0-3d34-4e25-8a1d-926a0a2cc9bb1688027201709' && cat > '/tmp/devcontainers-16d69df0-3d34-4e25-8a1d-926a0a2cc9bb1688027201709/env-loginInteractiveShell.json' << 'envJSON'
[2476 ms] Container server terminated (code: 127, signal: null).
[2479 ms] 
[2479 ms] 
[2493 ms] Command failed: /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/bin/code-server --log debug --force-disable-user-env --server-data-dir /root/.vscode-server --use-host-proxy --telemetry-level all --accept-server-license-terms --host 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --connection-token-file /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06 --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --start-server --disable-websocket-compression
[2494 ms] Error relocating /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/node: _ZNSt19_Sp_make_shared_tag5_S_eqERKSt9type_info: symbol not found
Error relocating /root/.vscode-server/bin/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
```

Here are the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml

```
FROM node:12.13.1-alpine as build-stage

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/test

WORKDIR /usr/src/test

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm install @quasar/cli@1.2.0
RUN npm rebuild node-sass
RUN npx quasar build

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npx", "quasar", "dev"]
```

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  test_frontend:
    container_name: test_frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5070:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/test
    networks:
      - test_network
networks:
  test_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here are versions I'm currently using:

- VS Code: 1.79.2
- Devcontainer extension: 0.295.0
- Docker:  24.0.2, build cb74dfc

I was expecting it to be attached properly to my VS Code IDE, but unfortunately due to unknown reason, it doesn't do it.